# How can I improve this Javascript calculation tool?

Tags: javascript

I am making a calculation tool. I am not very familiar with javascript, so my code looks a bit off. What edits should be made to make this tool work? I want the input numbers calculated just like the equation below:

```js
calculate = function()
{
  var x = document.getElementById('a').value;
  var y = document.getElementById('b').value;
  var z = document.getElementById('c').value; 
  document.getElementById('result').value = x * 588 + y * 28 + z + 44032
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="a" oninput="calculate()"/> × 588 +
<input type="number" id="b" oninput="calculate()"/> × 28 +
<input type="number" id="c" oninput="calculate()"/> + 44032 =
<input type='text' id="result"/>
```

equation:   **(x × 588) + (y × 28) + z + 44032 = result**

Comment: does adding the parentheses in the equation to the code help?

Comment: Code looks good but the missing semicolon.
What default value you want for each input ? 0 ? For example, for 0, use var x = document.getElementById('a').value || 0;
Yo, your input value will be a string, you need to convert it to an int/float to use it safely in an equation.

Comment: @Loenix The semicolon isn't "missing", see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When you use `document.getElementById` to get an `<input />` element it returns a JavaScript `object` of type `HTMLInputElement` which has the `.value` property (which you are using).
- However, the `HTMLInputElement.value` property returns a `string` value, not a `number` value.

  - You might be aware of the `valueAsNumber` property, however this does not work for `<input type="text" />` - only `<input type="number" />` (which your HTML is, fortunately), but always check for `NaN`!
- JavaScript is often described as being "loosely-typed" but I prefer to refer to it as being "wtfy-typed" because [its rules for implicit type conversions are inconsistent](https://github.com/denysdovhan/wtfjs).

  - A common "feature" in loosely-typed languages like JavaScript and PHP is [implicit conversion of `string` values to `number` values](https://2ality.com/2013/04/quirk-implicit-conversion.html), but it's best to avoid depending on that behaviour entirely and stick to always explicitly converting `string` values to `number` values using `parseInt(string,radix)`, `parseFloat(string)` or `Number(any)`.

So do this:

```js
var calculate = function()
{
    const x = parseFloat( document.getElementById('a').value );
    const y = parseFloat( document.getElementById('b').value );
    const z = parseFloat( document.getElementById('c').value );
    const o = document.getElementById('result');

    if( isNaN(x) || isNaN(y) || isNaN(z) ) {
        o.value = "Invalid input.";
    }
    else {
        const result = x * 588 + y * 28 + z + 44032;
        o.value = result.toString();
        // If `result` will be fractional then use `toFixed` instead of `toString`.
        // This is to avoid very long string representations of imprecise floating-point numbers due to how IEEE-754 works.
    }
}
```

```css
input[type=number] {
    text-align: right;
    width: 5em;
}
input#result {
    text-align: right;
    width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="a" oninput="calculate()" /> × 588 +
<input type="number" id="b" oninput="calculate()" /> × 28 +
<input type="number" id="c" oninput="calculate()" /> + 44032 =
<input type='text' id="result" readonly />
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript Types are playing games with you :), It is actually performing concatination.
when you read the values you have to just cast it to actual type which is number.
Here is the working code

```
<input type="number" id="a" oninput="calculate()"/> × 588 +
<input type="number" id="b" oninput="calculate()"/> × 28 +
<input type="number" id="c" oninput="calculate()"/> + 44032 =
<input type='text' id="result"/>
<script>
calculate = function()
{
  var x = Number(document.getElementById('a').value);
  var y = Number(document.getElementById('b').value);
  var z = Number(document.getElementById('c').value); 

  document.getElementById('result').value = (x * 588) + (y * 28) + z + 44032
}
</script>
```

There are other ways to achive the same like `ParseInt` and `ParseFloat`.
If you want the string to fail with NaN if it has other characters in it, `Number()` may actually be a better choice.

Because

```
Number('1234'); // returns 1234
Number('12.34'); // returns 12.34
Number('3.4040blahblahblac'); // returns NaN
Number('49cm'); // returns NaN
```

Comment: `parseInt` and `parseFloat` both also return `NaN` when they fail - except they have different rules for failure (`Number` parses the entire input string whereas `parseFloat`/`parseInt` allow strings that start with valid number text: https://thisthat.dev/number-constructor-vs-parse-int/

Comment: Yes you are right, I actually meant in the cases where I don't know exactly what type it is